# How can I get the PowerShell type accelerator list in an accelerated way?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, type-accelerators

According to [this TechNet article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/07/08/use-powershell-to-find-powershell-type-accelerators/) about PowerShell type accelerators, there are several dozens of type aliases called type accelerators. Indeed, the following command

```
[psobject].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")::get
```

returns 80 accelerators on my system.

However, the shorthand for it `[accelerators]::get` seems to fail:

> Unable to find type accelerators. Make sure that the assembly that
> contains this type is loaded. At line:1 char:1
>
> - 
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (accelerators:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
>   ```

I have also tried to dynamically load `System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators` assembly with `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")` before issuing the command, but it still fails.

`$PSVersionTable` returns the following data:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.18728
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

The OS is Windows 7 x64.

How can I get the PowerShell type accelerator list in an accelerated way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know the article says it's present by default in PowerShell 3.0, but I've never seen it in any other version out of the box, was likely removed again for the 4.0 release.

You'll need to add it yourself:

```
$TAType = [psobject].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")
$TAType::Add('accelerators',$TAType)

# this now works
[accelerators]::Get
```

Comment: Oh, so I have to add the accelerator. Thanks.

Comment: Unless you're on version 3.0 (Windows 8 / Server 2012), yes :-)

Comment: Seems like it was added back for PS 5 / Win 7.